# ng-grid : How to select the new row immediately

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I build a ng-grid and dynamically add a new row by clicking a button; however, the new row can not be selected immediately by using the grid options - [selectRow](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/).

here is the demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Kqw68GD09Jqqkrf1svGJ?p=preview

Does anyone can help me how to make the new row is being selected once it was inserted, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add `watch` with `$timeout` 0:

```
 $scope.$watch(function () {
       return $scope.myData;
    },
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
     $timeout(function(){
       $scope.gridOptions.selectRow(newValue.length-1,true);
     },0);
    }, true);
```

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gxGnLlg6GeScoJrLjkmP?p=preview)**</kbd>